# cakephp aes cookie cause crash of php

Tags: cakephp, aes, synology

I have an issue with cakephp 2. I have setup an AES cookie like this:

```
AppController.php

public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Cookie->name = 'mycookie';
    $this->Cookie->key = '12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890';
    $this->Cookie->type('aes');
}
```

doc: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/fr/core-libraries/components/cookie.html

This code cause crash only with apache that is installed on my synology NAS. But he work fine with easyphp (in local).

```
Warning (4096): Argument 1 passed to Hash::insert() must be an array, string given, called in /volume1/web/TEST_DEV/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/CookieComponent.php on line 249 and defined [CORE/Cake/Utility/Hash.php, line 257]

Notice (8): Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128' [CORE/Cake/Utility/Security.php, line 319]

Warning (4096): Argument 1 passed to Hash::insert() must be an array, string given, called in /volume1/web/TEST_DEV/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/CookieComponent.php on line 249 and defined [CORE/Cake/Utility/Hash.php, line 257]

Notice (8): Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128' [CORE/Cake/Utility/Security.php, line 319]

Notice (8): Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_MODE_CBC - assumed 'MCRYPT_MODE_CBC' [CORE/Cake/Utility/Security.php, line 320]

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_get_iv_size() in /volume1/web/TEST_DEV/lib/Cake/Utility/Security.php on line 322
```

Can someone help me ? Because many of my dev are done on my synology NAS...

Edit: phpinfo() give me this output for the column ***Configure Command***

```
'./configure.syno' '--host=armle-unknown-linux' '--target=armle-unknown-linux' '--build=i686-pc-linux' '--with-ldap=shared,/usr/syno' '--with-ldap-sasl=/usr/syno' '--prefix=/usr/syno/php' '--with-apxs2=/usr/syno/apache/bin/apxs' '--disable-cgi' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/syno/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/syno/etc/php' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr/syno' '--with-bz2=/usr/syno' '--with-zlib=shared,/usr/syno' '--enable-bcmath=shared' '--enable-syno_compiler=shared' '--enable-calendar=shared' '--with-curl=shared,/usr/syno' '--enable-dba=shared' '--enable-exif=shared' '--enable-ftp=shared' '--with-gd=shared' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/syno' '--with-png-dir=/usr/syno' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr/syno' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-gettext=shared' '--with-iconv=shared,/usr/syno/libiconv' '--with-imap=shared,/source/imap-2007e' '--with-imap-ssl=shared,/usr/syno' '--enable-mbstring=shared' '--with-mcrypt=shared,/usr/syno' '--with-mysql=shared,/usr/syno/mysql' '--with-mysqli=shared,/usr/syno/mysql/bin/mysql_config' '--with-openssl=shared,/usr/syno' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared,/usr/syno/mysql' '--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/usr/syno/pgsql' '--with-pgsql=shared,/usr/syno/pgsql' '--enable-shmop=shared' '--enable-soap=shared' '--enable-sockets=shared' '--enable-wddx=shared' '--with-xmlrpc=shared' '--enable-zip=shared' '--with-sqlite3=static,/usr/syno/sqlite3' '--with-pdo-sqlite=static,/usr/syno/sqlite3' '--with-xsl=shared,/usr/syno/libxslt' '--enable-phar=shared' '--with-mssql=shared,/usr/syno/freetds'
```

So i think that mcrypt is correctly installed ...

edit 26/01/2015: many forums report that mcrypt has issue with synology NAS

Comment: If MCRYPT_REJNDAEL_128 is undefined, it probably means there's a problem with PHP's mcrypt library.  Like it's not installed or not being loaded or something.

Comment: how can i check if mcrypt is installed ?

Comment: Add `echo phpinfo();` to your page is one the easiest ways.  Then scan the output for mcrypt.  Make sure to remove that line when you're done.  You don't want others to be able to see that information.

Comment: see my edit, i think that mcrypt is already installed on my system ...

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found what's happen. Synology disable mcrypt in the default configuration.

For correct this behavior.

into your admin pannel of synology: http://diskstation:5000/webman/index.cgi

1. Select Web Services
2. Click On tab Php Settings
3. Click on Php extension
4. Check mcrypt

(screenshot here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEEv5.jpg)